# Ajax Jquery - Data Type JSON always response null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to create a simple jQuery Ajax code to check user discount code when someone click "Check Discount Code" button. I created this prototype:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $("#btn-check-discount").click(function() {
        checkdiscountcode();
    });

    // end document ready

    function checkdiscountcode() {
        var discountValue = $("#discount_code").val();
        var nonce = "<?php echo wp_create_nonce("
        getdiscount_nonce "); ?>";
        alert(discountValue);
        alert(nonce);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url() . "
            admin - ajax.php " ?>",
            data: {
                action: "getdiscount",
                discountValue: discountValue
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                if (response.message == "found") {
                    alert("Code Correct");
                } else {
                    alert("Code InCorrect!!! Please Try it Again");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Functions.php:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getdiscount", "getdiscount");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount", "getdiscount");

function getdiscount() {

    $return = array(
            'message'   => 'Found',
            'ID'        => 1
    );
    wp_send_json($return);
}
```

This code is not working. I have added some alert(response), hoping I will get `Array()` response from the alert, but it keep gives me "Null".
Can anyone helps me to find the culprit? I implemented this code in WordPress 3.9.3.

Comment: did you try with dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json" ?

Comment: What happens if you hit the endpoint url directly in your browser?

Comment: @Kalish : After add contentType: "application/json", the response become 0. Is there any other advise?

Comment: @Carl : I think what you meant about endpoint url is admin-ajax.php, when I tried to directly open admin-ajax.php, it gives me 0 response (http://fractionalpartners2.linux.stagingreview.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `add_action` hooks as like below and give it a try:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getdiscount", "getdiscount");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount", "getdiscount"); // remove '2' from wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount
```

instead of

```
add_action("wp_ajax_getdiscount", "getdiscount");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount2", "getdiscount");
```

Comment: I'm sorry I meant wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount. I already fix my question. I already tried with wp_ajax_nopriv_getdiscount, but my code still not working.